# Erase part of string in php if same character until the end

Tags: php

Suppose I have a string as following:

> 11221211111212111111211111222222222

And what I want to obtain:

> 11221211111212111111211111

Basically, I just erased the last '2's since the *"first one" of the last*, if that makes any sense. I've considered running the string with a foreach but I'd like to check up for a code-friendlier alternative, in means of performance and readibility...

Comment: `rtrim($string,2)` ?

Comment: `preg_replace('/(.)\1*$/', '', $string)` is another way.

Comment: @smistry http://images.sodahead.com/polls/000259252/polls_have_i_told_you_lately_that_i_love_you_2232_493788_poll_xlarge.gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string = "11221211111212111111211111222222222";  
$newString = rtrim($string, substr($string, -1));
echo $newString;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `rtrim()` method may be faster than using a regular expression, but you can match this [expression](http://regex101.com/r/lW5mT9) and replace it with nothing:

```
(.)\1*$
```

That will capture any character (`(.)`) and then match 0+ more of that captured character (`\1*`) until the end of the string (`$`).  Use this with PHP's [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) like so:

```
$string = '11221211111212111111211111222222222';
$string = preg_replace('/(.)\1*$/', '', $string);

var_dump($string);
// string(26) "11221211111212111111211111"
```